# Copying a folder into dist/

Tags: haskell, cabal

I want to copy a folder full of assets next to my executable during distribution. How can I represent this in the .cabal file (or, alternatively, the Setup.hs)?

Directory structure:

```
root/
    dist/ -- Generated by cabal
    src/
    assets/
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

List them in your `extra-source-files` or `data-files` field. More information is available in the cabal manual, especially [the section on retrieving data files](https://www.haskell.org/cabal/users-guide/developing-packages.html#accessing-data-files-from-package-code).